# access vba go to acNewRec scrolling

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using `DoCmd.GoToRecord ,,acNewRec` in a continuous subform Form Open event.

That causes the continuous form to scroll so that only the new record is visible.  I'd like to show 4-5 records above the new record row.

In Form View the new record navigation at the bottom does the same thing, so it seems to be a default Access behavior.

I've tried several combinations of moving in the recordset before and after and then go back to the new record, but I can't get it to work. Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Control the scroll bar - I think there is example code in database at http://www.lebans.com/setgetsb.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ms Access VBA go to last record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748681/ms-access-vba-go-to-last-record)